# Heroku recognize non exist model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I tried to upload my rails3.2 app on Heroku.
I followed the instruction on Heroku and could uploaded that.

After I opened the app, I got error.
I ran "heroku logs" and got

```
    2012-07-21T19:07:01+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Thin
    2012-07-21T19:07:01+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.6 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:34125
    2012-07-21T19:07:01+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
    2012-07-21T19:07:01+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
    2012-07-21T19:07:01+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
    2012-07-21T19:07:01+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require':   /app/app/models/question.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting tASSOC (SyntaxError)
```

This log says I have SyntaxError in 'question.rb', but I've already deleted that model before. So, it means Heroku recognized non exist model.

I tried "heroku pg:reset SHARED_DATABASE" and "bundle exec rake db:drop:all"
But Heroku still mis-recognize the model.

How can I fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you haven't removed the model file from your git repository.

First let's check if you still have the model file in your git repo. This is to check whether if what I suspect is the problem.

Do `git log` in your terminal

Copy the git commit code for the most recent commit that looks something like `af99fe31c0598a8aezecf704c68d20c153ccad9c`

Do `git ls-tree -r --name-only af99fe31c0598a8aezecf704c68d20c153ccad9c` in your terminal.

Most likely, you'll still find the model file in the list.

Do `git rm /app/app/models/question.rb`

Commit whatever changes, and push to Heroku.

Do `heroku run rake db:migrate` and `heroku restart`

See if the problem still occurs.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I tried git rm /app/app/models/question.rb and it worked! Thank you so much.